Using "for in" over a string to find a character but then not able to use the variable to reference another value
Still learning JS and confused over this
The below code gives out undefined as output when it should be "v" - am I missing something or using for-in over a string is the issue


let s="iydafgvb";
var i = 0
for(i in s){
    if(s.charAt(i)=="a"){
        break;
    }
} 
console.log(s.charAt(i));



Expecting "v" but getting "undefined"

I've converted your code to a snippet.  Running it returns the expected a not undefined and not v.  Please [edit] the question to provide the code that demonstrates the issue. See [mcve]

Both s and i are declared before the loop, they are also available after the loop. The value of s.charAt(i) is still 'a' after the loop because the loop breaks when s.charAt(i) === 'a'. Print i and s.charAt(i), inside the loop and after the loop to see how it works. The value of i should be 3 after the loop (because string character indices and array indices start from 0 in JavaScript).

for...in is intended for use with objects, not strings:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

You cant use for(char in string) in js and use char as the actual character. To iterate over a string you should use for of: for(let char of string). You can now access the characters with the char variable:


let text = "hello"

for(let char of text){
  console.log(char);
}

/* this will output

h
e
l
l
o
*/



You can also convert the string to an array: let array = Array.from(text). Now you can use array like a regular array.

"You cant use for(char in string) in js" - why not?  What makes you think this?
It works fine in the snippet I added using OPs code.  for..in returns an iterator index while the (newer!) for..of returns the actual values.  Both have their uses.

@fdomn-m Sorry for the confusion, thats what i meant.
